# positioning the child behind the parent of the parent element, ```z-index``` does not work

Tags: html, css

I want the `<span>` to appear behind the `#sideBar` i tried `z-index: -3` but that didn't work

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: "Signika Negative", sans-serif;
  background-color: #252525;
  color: #f8f9fa;
  user-select: none;
}

#sideBar{
  width: 2vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(15, 15, 15);
  opacity: .99;
}

.menuBtn{
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .5vw;
  border: none;
  padding: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1vmax;
}

.menuBtn .label{
  transition: left .5s;
}

.label{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: .9vmax;
  opacity: 1;
  left: -2.2vw;
}

svg{
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.menuBtn:hover svg{
  transform: scale(1.2);
}



.menuBtn:hover .label{
  opacity: 1;
  left: 2.2vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Mono&family=Signika+Negative:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <style>
        @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Mono&family=Signika+Negative:wght@300&display=swap");
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>OverStat</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="sideBar">
        <div class="menuBtn" onclick="clear()"><span class="label" >Clear all games and ranks</span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 448 512"><path fill="lightgrey" d="M135.2 17.7C140.6 6.8 151.7 0 163.8 0H284.2c12.1 0 23.2 6.8 28.6 17.7L320 32h96c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32H32C14.3 96 0 81.7 0 64S14.3 32 32 32h96l7.2-14.3zM32 128H416V448c0 35.3-28.7 64-64 64H96c-35.3 0-64-28.7-64-64V128zm96 64c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V432c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16s16-7.2 16-16V208c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16zm96 0c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V432c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16s16-7.2 16-16V208c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16zm96 0c-8.8 0-16 7.2-16 16V432c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16s16-7.2 16-16V208c0-8.8-7.2-16-16-16z"/></svg></div>

        <div class="menuBtn"><span class="label">Prefrences</span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.3.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. --><path fill="lightgrey" d="M0 416c0-17.7 14.3-32 32-32l54.7 0c12.3-28.3 40.5-48 73.3-48s61 19.7 73.3 48L480 384c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-246.7 0c-12.3 28.3-40.5 48-73.3 48s-61-19.7-73.3-48L32 448c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32zm192 0a32 32 0 1 0 -64 0 32 32 0 1 0 64 0zM384 256a32 32 0 1 0 -64 0 32 32 0 1 0 64 0zm-32-80c32.8 0 61 19.7 73.3 48l54.7 0c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-54.7 0c-12.3 28.3-40.5 48-73.3 48s-61-19.7-73.3-48L32 288c-17.7 0-32-14.3-32-32s14.3-32 32-32l246.7 0c12.3-28.3 40.5-48 73.3-48zM192 64a32 32 0 1 0 0 64 32 32 0 1 0 0-64zm73.3 0L480 64c17.7 0 32 14.3 32 32s-14.3 32-32 32l-214.7 0c-12.3 28.3-40.5 48-73.3 48s-61-19.7-73.3-48L32 128C14.3 128 0 113.7 0 96S14.3 64 32 64l86.7 0C131 35.7 159.2 16 192 16s61 19.7 73.3 48z"/></svg></div>

        <div class="menuBtn"><span class="label">How to use</span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.3.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2023 Fonticons, Inc. --><path fill="lightgrey" d="M256 512A256 256 0 1 0 256 0a256 256 0 1 0 0 512zM216 336h24V272H216c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24s10.7-24 24-24h48c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24v88h8c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24s-10.7 24-24 24H216c-13.3 0-24-10.7-24-24s10.7-24 24-24zm40-208a32 32 0 1 1 0 64 32 32 0 1 1 0-64z"/></svg></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid - you cannot have duplicate ID on any elements in the same document. "I want the <span> to appear behind " - which span you have multiple.

Comment: all of them and sorry for the duplicate ID's i was copying and pasting them i will take them out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put `opacity: .99` on the `#sidebar`, it forms a stacking context on `#sidebar` and everything inside it is stuck on it even if you put a `z-index: -1000`.

```
#sidebar {
   opacity: 1;
}
.label {
   z-index: -3;
}
```

Read more about the [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Comment: Thank you, i didn't have any idea that opacity would affect stacking i put it for the looks.